# URL Rewriting in PHP causing problems

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Here is my .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ profile.php?user=$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

here is profile.php:

```
if(isset($_GET['user']) && strlen($_GET['user'])>0) {
    $userreal = $_GET['user'];
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT username FROM users WHERE username=?");
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $userreal);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();
    if($stmt->num_rows == 1) {
        $user = $_GET['user'];
    }
    else {
        $us = $_SESSION['username'];
        header("Location: profile/" . $us);
        exit();
    }
    $stmt->close();
}
else {
    $us = $_SESSION['username'];
    header("Location: profile/" . $us);
    exit();
}
```

This is my redirecting part (thought it might be helpful).

but it redirects me to:

```
http://localhost/PHP/Projects/HassanTech/pages/profile/profile/profile/profile/profile/profile/profile/profile/profile/profile/profile/profile/profile/profile/profile/profile/profile/profile/profile/profile/profile/Hassan
```

when I try to access

```
http://localhost/PHP/Projects/HassanTech/pages/profile
```

I want my links:

```
http://localhost/PHP/Projects/HassanTech/pages/profile?user=Hassan
```

to

```
http://localhost/PHP/Projects/HassanTech/pages/profile/Hassan
```

My .htaccess file is in the pages folder and the profile.php is in the pages folder. Hope you can help me.

Comment: Posted an answer on the other question you posted, is this related to the same problem?

Answer (score 1):

Change your header redirect to use `./` and you will stay in the same directory thus resolving your problem:

```
header("Location: ./" . $us);
```

Comment: The URL works fine, now, but I get "This webpage has a redirect loop" and cannot access the site.

Comment: This is because you are creating an infinite loop. You begin by saying (via your `RewriteRule`) "I want all links structured like `/pages/profile/Hassan` to point to `pages/profile.php?user=Hassan`". Then you are saying (in your PHP), "Okay, if I can't find a user with that $_GET["user"] value OR if $_GET["user"] is not defined, then redirect to /pages/profile/Hassan which is already the page that you are on... hence the infinite loop.

Comment: You need to either change your approach to checking for a user or modify your first `if` condition.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^pages/profile/([^/]+)/?$ pages/profile.php?user=$1 [L,NC,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]
```

Did the trick for me. :]